# How should I manage glActiveTexture with regard to initializing textures?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, webgl

I'm using WebGL (≈ OpenGL ES 2.0). At the moment, my application uses texture unit 0 as a per-model texture, and 1 and 2 as constant textures used by the shader.

In order to load and set up a texture, I do

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(...);
gl.texParameteri(...);
```

However, this stomps on the state of which texture is bound to the current texture unit. In order to avoid this program, I added

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
```

to the beginning of the above code, so that it only affects the binding for texture unit 0 which is reset before drawing any geometry anyway.

Is there a better approach, i.e. one that does not involve happening to have a “scratch” texture unit available? Is there an established best practice for this state management problem?

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue comes under the same category as a few other: what can you assume about the GL state at certain points in the program?

AFAICT you basically have two options:

1. assume nothing, and set the state the way you need it.  i.e. call `glActiveTextrure()` as you are currently doing
2. set rules for what state the GL should be in at certain points in your program. e.g. for your case, have the drawing part call `glActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE0)` when it is done, so the pre-drawing parts can assume it's set that way.

But really, don't think too much about it.  In OpenGL you optimise your program by maximising (within certain practical limits) the ratio of polygons to function calls, which you can do as well by passing lots of polygons do your `glDrawArrays()` calls etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking "what should the policy for the active texture unit be?" — I already follow the principles you described — but "how should I initialize textures with the least disturbance to my other uses of texture units?", which might suggest constraints on the rules.

Comment: You could read that as another instance of what I was talking about.  In GL There is a lot of state that can be 'stomped on' like that.  You could use a separate texture unit for that work, which means you don't have to reset anything but you have to call `glActiveTextureUnit()` twice.  Or you could clobber the current texture unit and then pass the responsibility of setting up the texture state to the drawing part.  Either way, part of your program (sort of) has some extra work to do.

Comment: Going one way or the other it comes down to a *small* trade-off between efficiency and maintainability.